# How can i get trimmed multiple parameters value by using extract($_REQUEST)

Tags: php, parameters, extract

How can i get  trimmed multiple parameters value by using extract($_REQUEST)

```
process.php?ticketid=101 & TrID=902121

extract($_REQUEST);

echo $ticketid;// result  " 101 "
echo $TrID;//result   " 902121 "
```

Comment: Call `trim` after using `extract`. BTW, using `extract` is a really bad idea. what if someone puts something in the URL that overwrites one of your important variables?

Comment: Why are you putting spaces in your URL in the first place?

Comment: @Barmar  thanks,  ur right , if avoid spaces it 've no space but sometime we get unwanted spaces when extract request..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first remove spaces from your url like this:

`process.php?ticketid=101&TrID=902121`

```
extract($_REQUEST);

// looping through all elements of $_REQUEST
foreach($_REQUEST as $key=>$val){

  $arr[$key] = trim($val);
}
print_r(arr);
```